# UTF-8 characters displaying issue in linux server

Tags: java, linux, utf-8, character-encoding

we have a project in Java and a simple logic for uploading txt files from frontend with user names and some data(phone numbers, ID numbers, etc.), and some names have UTF-8 characters like ü, ə, ö (azeri language). when I parse the file from my locale system (Windows 8.1, Netbeans 8, Java 1.8), all characters display correctly in user's browser. but after deploying the project to the server(Red Hat, Java 1.8), Ə characters display like question marks. this is my code:

```
    for (byte[] value : file) {
        try {
            Charset.availableCharsets().get("UTF-8").newDecoder().decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(value));
            decodedString += new String(value, "UTF-8"); // 1
        } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
            decodedString += new String(value, Charset.forName("cp866")); // 2
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AllotmentItem.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

in this code I check is the file in UTF-8 format (1) or in CP866 (2), if in UTF, then I just concat it, else I convert the symbols to the utf-8 (another code part). and I can't understand why in linux I get question marks.

EDIT:
When I debug in my locale machine, in debug console I get utf-8 names with question marks, but in final stage in user's browser everythig is ok.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Could you please provide an example (the byte values) for `value` where the encoding fails?

Comment: This comes from not being able to convert a Unicode character (code point) to some encoding. It could be that somewhere an encoding parameter was not given, and an overloaded method with default platform encoding was used. Could also happen with FileReader/FileWriter or `String.getBytes()`

Comment: do you mean a shell `debug console`  (like bash, ksh, zsh)?. If so, then `echo $TERM`. You'll probably see `VT100` or `XTERM`. You'll have to look around for a terminal setting that can handle UTF-8. (I don't know what that would be). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter no, I mean when I debug in Netbeans, in debug info I also see uncorrect symbols, but in browser ON WINDOWS system everything is OK. but when I deploy project to the linux machine, I see uncorrect symbols like when I debuged.

Comment: Does `value` contains all bytes of a file or it can be only a part of a file? If it can be a part of file then your algorithm will fail on bound of a character.